# Getting System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException while trying to run WP8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am writing Windows Phone 8 application and using MVVM light. I have written ViewModel and Model class of WP8 app into seperate PCL project.

While using Expression Blend it properly populate design time data. But when I try to run app in emulator it get following error. Could you please help me in figuring out the fix to this error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' 
occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

Here is details of Exception.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Cannot create instance of type 'MyPkg.Commons.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator' [Line: 12 Position: 61]
  Source=System.Windows
  LineNumber=12
  LinePosition=61
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at MyPkg.WindowsPhone8.App.InitializeComponent()
       at MyPkg.WindowsPhone8.App..ctor()
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=The type initializer for 'MyPkg.Commons.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator' threw an exception.
       Source=mscorlib
       TypeName=MyPkg.Commons.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
            at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass32.<GetCreateObjectDelegate>b__2c()
            at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)
            at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.CreateInstance(XamlTypeToken inXamlType, XamlQualifiedObject& newObject)
       InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException
            HResult=-2146234304
            Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
            Source=MyPkg.Commons
            StackTrace:
                 at MyPkg.Commons.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator..cctor()
            InnerException:
```

Below is App.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
             xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyPkg.Commons.ViewModel;assembly=MyPkg.Commons"
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MyPkg.WindowsPhone8.App">
  <!--Application Resources-->
  <Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyPkg.WindowsPhone8" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"  />
  </Application.Resources>
  <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated" />
  </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
</Application>
```

Below code constructor of ViewModelLocator

```cs
   static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            // Create design time view services and models
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAlaramService, MyPkg.Commons.Design.AlaramService>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create run time view services and models
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IAlaramService, MyPkg.Commons.Design.AlaramService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there's a problem with your reference to the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation assembly. Open the References folder for your project, right click on Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, and choose properties. Ensure that the file referenced at the Path exists and that Copy Local is set to True, then rebuild the application. If this error persists, remove and re-add the MVVM Light library to your project.

Comment: Thank you,  commons (my PCL library) and wp8 project were referring to different version of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation. I made both to refer to PCL version of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation and it started working.